# Why is there a segmentation fault in this code ?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I want to compare two strings of numbers, to count each occurences of the same numeral

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void function(string number1, string number2)
{
   int taille = number1.size();
   int tab[]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
   int chiffre=0;

   for (int i=0; i<taille;i++) {
       for (int j=0;j<taille;j++){
           if (number1[i]==number2[j])
           {
              cout <<  "chiffre " <<number1[i]<< endl;
              chiffre = number1[i];
              tab[chiffre]++; 
           }
        }
   }

   for (int i=0; i<10;i++) {
       if (tab[i]!=0)
       cout << "index " << i<< " value "<<  tab[i]<< endl;
   }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

     string number1 = "5143436111";
     string number2 = "4501234567";
    function(number1,number2);
    cout << "Press the enter key to continue ...";
    cin.get();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The line with tab[chiffre]++; seems to crash the program. Please explain me why

Comment: Please, use debugger!

Comment: Thanks to everybody, problem is solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
chiffre = number1[i]-'0';
```

Also, you have this:

```
   int taille = number1.size();
```

But what if number1 and number2 are different sizes? Then your inner loop (e.g. `for (int j=0;j<taille;j++)` could index out of number2 if number2 is smaller than number1, or it won't loop enough if number2 is larger than number1.

Answer (score 1):

in this line:

```
chiffre = number1[i];
```

you are converting a character ('5' for example) into an integer. It should be:

```
chiffre = number1[i] - '0';
```

I don't know what you want to obtain exactly, but I suppose you only want to compare the first number in number1 with the first in number2 and that you presuppose two numbers of the same length? In that case your loop should become this:

```
if (number1.size() == number2.size()){
    for (int i=0; i<taille;i++) {
           if (number1[i]==number2[i])
           {
              cout <<  "chiffre " <<number1[i]<< endl;
              chiffre = number1[i] - '0';
              tab[chiffre]++; 
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: While the general idea is right, `atoi()` expects a string, not a character.

Answer (score 1):

`number1[i]` contains some character as for example `'5'`. Its ASCII code is 53. The array has no 53 elements.

So change this statement

```
          chiffre = number1[i];
```

to

```
          chiffre = number1[i] - '0';
```

Also your algorithm does not work correctly. For example if number1 is equal to `"55"` and number2 is equal to `45` then your algorithm prints that digit 5 is contained in number2 two times.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line:

```
chiffre = number1[i];
```

When you assign the number to `chiffre`, it will not assign it as a number (from 0 to 9), but as an ASCII code (from '0' to '9').

You can transform it to a number using this:

```
chiffre = number1[i] - '0';
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use tab ["5"] you're using the ascii value of 5 which is 53, going out of the 10 bound
You need to cast the ascii value or use tab [chiffre-48]
48 is'0' in ascii